# Zend Framework Navigation, escape option to view html within a title?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-navigation

Alright, I can't find this option anywhere.  I'm generating Zend Navigation through the database and into an multi-dimensional array through recursion, cake.  So, some of these titles have html in them or html special chars.  So, why can't I find the escape option anywhere so I can display these things.  Any insight into this maze of framework options would be greatly appreciated.

```
$this->navigation()
   ->menu()
   ->setUlClass('navbar')
   ->setMinDepth(0)
   ->setMaxDepth(0)
   ->setRenderParents(false) 
   ->setOnlyActiveBranch(false);
```

Comment: Apparently it was a bug in my version that was fixed in the latest.

http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-10458

Apply the patch and create your own view helper. and take off the $this->view->escape($label) to just $label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-define `Zend_View_Abstract` `escape()` behaviour, be default it's using `htmlspecialchars`.

Example in bootstrap:

```
protected function _initNav()
{
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $view->setEscape(function($var){ 
        return $var; });
}
```

Comment: That does work, though, we have a lot of forms and it doesn't escape user input with something like this.  Is there a way to specifically target the nav without getting the entire page without overwriting Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu? +1 though, thank you for the response that does accomplish what I need.